# Method not being executed when leaving a component with componentWillUnmount()

Tags: reactjs, components

I need to check between Facebook's expiration date and the current date when I enter in two different components. `Dashboard` and `Pages`. Both have this:

```
componentWillMount() {
  const { linkedAccount, clearLinkedAccounts, getFacebookPages } = this.props
  const now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')

  if (linkedAccount) {
    if (now < linkedAccount.expiresIn) {
      getFacebookPages()
    } else {
      clearLinkedAccounts()
    }
  }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  const { linkedAccount, clearLinkedAccounts } = this.props
  const now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')

  if (linkedAccount && now > linkedAccount.expiresIn) {
    clearLinkedAccounts()
  }
}
```

But only when refreshing the page manually, the `clearLinkedAccounts()` is executed, by running `componentWillMount`, but before leaving it, it doesn't. I want it to be executed, if necessary, before entering in another route.

Comment: Can you provide the react router codes too?

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the page is not like going from a page to another page inside the same single app context. [React router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) allows you to go from a page to another within a React single app with tag like `Link`. It is why react router is so useful!

When you click on a link to go to another page with `Link`, the React single app is still active. As a result, `componentWillUnmount` wil lbe called because the single app is able to unmount component.

When you refresh the page (F5), a new page is loaded. As a result, the entire existing single app is removed and given to the browser garbage collector. In that case, you have no control on React component. So impossible to call `componentWillUnmount` because there is no more components at all.